# Call timeAgoSinceDate Function Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and I was wondering the proper way to call this function. I also would like to know the proper way to use this function to return a string back to the view controller. Any advice for the newbie would help.

**Solution:**

```
let now = NSDate()
let timeString = timeAgoSinceDate(date: now, numericDates: false)
```

**NEW QUESTION:**

How can I implement this when assigning a time stamp to a tableViewCell so that it updates frequently without causing problems

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage


func UploadGeneralChatRoom(message : String) {

    //Firebase Initialization
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    //var storage: FIRStorageReference!
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    //storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()


    //Get Data from database resend to database
    if let userId = userID {
    ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
        let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

        let now = NSDate()

        ref.child("general_room").childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userId, "Message" : message, "time_stamp" : now, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])



//        ref.child("general_room").child("chat").child(userID!).childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userID!, "Message" : message, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])







    })

}

}//END func



  import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import AlamofireImage
import Alamofire

struct postStruct {
    let username : String!
    let message : String!
    let photoURL : String!
    let timeStamp: String!
}



class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var generalRoomDataArr = [postStruct]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //TableView Cell word wrap (Dynamic Text)
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 78
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension



        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        //let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid


    ref.child("general_room").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
        let message = snapDict?["Message"] as? String ?? ""
        let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

        //Time Stamp string
        let now = NSDate()
        let timeString = timeAgoSinceDate(date: now, numericDates: false)
        print("Time: " + timeString)

        self.generalRoomDataArr.insert(postStruct(username: username, message: message, photoURL: firebaseUserPhotoURL, timeStamp: timeString), at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()



    })

}


@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToRoom", sender: nil)
}


//Message Send button is pressed data uploaded to firebase
@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {



    //If a character exists will be uploaded to firebase
    if ((messageTextField.text?.characters.count)! > 0) {

    let message : String = self.messageTextField.text!
    UploadGeneralChatRoom(message: message) //upload to general_room
    self.messageTextField.text = nil
    messageTextField.resignFirstResponder()//Quit keyboard

    self.tableView.reloadData() //Reload tableView
    //UploadUserData() //Update Rank in database

    }


}








func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return generalRoomDataArr.count // your number of cell here
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {




    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    //Set username label to display username
    let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username

    //Set message label to display message
    let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    //initialize UI Profile Image
    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

    //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Set timeStampLabel to current time AGO
    let timeStampLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    timeStampLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].timeStamp

    //Loading and change of Usesrs profile image on chat cell
    let userProfileChatImage = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL

    //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library
    let downloadURL = NSURL(string: userProfileChatImage!)
    imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL as! URL)

    // your cell coding
    return cell!
}
```

}//END CLASS

```
func timeAgoSinceDate(date:NSDate, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfYear, .month, .year, .second]
        let now = NSDate()
        let earliest = now.earlierDate(date as Date)
        let latest = (earliest == now as Date) ? date : now
        let components = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: earliest as Date,  to: latest as Date)

        if (components.year! >= 2) {
            return "\(components.year!) years ago"
        } else if (components.year! >= 1){
            if (numericDates){
                return "1 year ago"
            } else {
                return "Last year"
            }
        } else if (components.month! >= 2) {
            return "\(components.month!) months ago"
        } else if (components.month! >= 1){
            if (numericDates){
                return "1 month ago"
            } else {
                return "Last month"
            }
        } else if (components.weekOfYear! >= 2) {
            return "\(components.weekOfYear!) weeks ago"
        } else if (components.weekOfYear! >= 1){
            if (numericDates){
                return "1 week ago"
            } else {
                return "Last week"
            }
        } else if (components.day! >= 2) {
            return "\(components.day!) days ago"
        } else if (components.day! >= 1){
            if (numericDates){
                return "1 day ago"
            } else {
                return "Yesterday"
            }
        } else if (components.hour! >= 2) {
            return "\(components.hour!) hours ago"
        } else if (components.hour! >= 1){
            if (numericDates){
                return "1 hour ago"
            } else {
                return "An hour ago"
            }
        } else if (components.minute! >= 2) {
            return "\(components.minute!) minutes ago"
        } else if (components.minute! >= 1){
            if (numericDates){
                return "1 minute ago"
            } else {
                return "A minute ago"
            }
        } else if (components.second! >= 3) {
            return "\(components.second!) seconds ago"
        } else {
            return "Just now"
        }

    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? And why you want to call this function? (reason)
So we could suggest you.

Comment: Im trying to put a time stamp on a tableView cell.

Comment: Every time when you open the view, call it on viewWillAppear (So that it loads the time stamps.) and every time when you update the table view.

Comment: ok im going to give it a shot

Comment: Also if you are updating the tableView keep a copy of NSDate somewhere in CoreData so that you can retrieve and send that to this function using that value.. So the time stamp will be correct. Can I know from where is the dataSource of your tableview?

Comment: Ok so i updated my code and the output works ok but im not sure if my logic is correct with updating the vaue. give it a look.

Comment: All my outputs are "just now" i dont think i set it up right to constantly update. Yeah ll the outputs are stuck at "Just now" how can i constantly update it from the code I have now.

Comment: don't use chengsam's solution. it will always return just now... Wait I will give you a solution

Comment: You have to call the function in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Comment: have a look at my answer then you'll get to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SEND Data in following manner**

```
let now = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let nowString = dateFormatter.string(from: now)

ref.child("general_room").childByAutoId().setValue(["Usernam‌​e": username, "uid": userId, "Message" : message, "time_stamp" : nowString, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])
```

**Receive data in following manner**

```
  ref.child("general_room").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

    let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
    let message = snapDict?["Message"] as? String ?? ""
    let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

    if let timeString = snapDict?["timeStamp"] as? String {

      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
      let timeStampDate = dateFormatter.date(from: timeString)
      let timeStamp = timeAgoSinceDate(date: timeStampDate, numericDates: false)
      print("Time: " + timeStamp)
    }
    self.generalRoomDataArr.insert(postStruct(username: username, message: message, photoURL: firebaseUserPhotoURL, timeStamp: timeStamp), at: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

**UPDATE in your method**

```
func timeAgoSinceDate(date:Date, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfYear, .month, .year, .second]
let now = NSDate()
let earliest = now.earlierDate(date as Date)
let latest = (earliest == now as Date) ? date : now as Date
let components = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: earliest as Date,  to: latest as Date)
```

Comment: I sent it to firebase as a String so the "time_stamp " = just now. Is that how i should upload it? or should it be a difeerent value?

Comment: can you show me what value i need to send to firebase. Because i just sent the timeString value

Comment: do I send let now = NSDate() this value? and how would i do that. How do i initialize it and send it to firebase as a non string.

Comment: whenever you insert an entry in to FIRDatabase send a timeStamp of NSDate to it with a name "timeStamp". then retrieve like above.. you will get the timeAgoSinceDate

Comment: let now = NSDate()

Comment: ref.child("general_room").childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userId, "Message" : message, "time_stamp" : now, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])

Comment: im just kind of confused what to send to fireBase data base. its not letting me send a Date value

Comment: thats how i send the data. Can you show me how and what value to send under "time_Stamp". i updated the code to show you how i send it to database

Comment: how do i get the time stmp and do i send it as a String to firebase?>\

Comment: let timeStamp = timeAgoSinceDate(date: timeStampDate, numericDates: false) cannot convert value of type Date?

Comment: Update your method.. only update above mentioned lines

Comment: Ok last thing is this line let nowString = dateFormatter.string(from: date1)......date1?

Comment: not date1 instead use now..

I mistakenly wrote that.

Comment: App crashing let timeStampDate = dateFormatter.date(from: timeString!) EXC BAD INSTRUCTION not sure why.

Comment: it sends null value.. DB won't have value for previous entries.. delete the data of DB and start again.. also check updated answer

Comment: Deleted all the data now it crashes here with same instruction. let timeStampDate = dateFormatter.date(from: timeString!)

Comment: Ok now it works but my time stamp value is 2017-03-05 and it sais 26 minutes ago

Comment: you must have inserted that 26 minutes ago. its okay if it previous date. after 24 hours it will change to yesterday and then go on

Comment: The time stamp sais 20 minutes ago. So how is this gana work if the recent output claims 20 minutes behind?

Comment: its difficult to understand what you are passing and how you're doing that. but though to avoid crashing put a `if let` condition in timeStamp. then put a debug point inside that if it stops then check exact value. if you want to do for minutes till seconds then you can change the dateFormatter. These are minor details that anyone won't tell you. you have to learn and adapt. `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that seeks working timeAgoSinceDate function in **Swift 3.0**

```
func timeAgoSinceDate(date:Date, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let unitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfYear, .month, .year]
    let now = NSDate()
    let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components(unitFlags, from: date, to: now as Date, options: [])

    if (components.year! >= 2) {
        return "\(components.year!)" + " years ago".localized()
    } else if (components.year! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 year ago".localized()
        } else {
            return "Last year".localized()
        }
    } else if (components.month! >= 2) {
        return "\(components.month!)" + " months ago".localized()
    } else if (components.month! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 month ago".localized()
        } else {
            return "Last month".localized()
        }
    } else if (components.weekOfYear! >= 2) {
        return "\(components.weekOfYear!)" + " weeks ago".localized()
    } else if (components.weekOfYear! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 week ago".localized()
        } else {
            return "Last week".localized()
        }
    } else if (components.day! >= 2) {
        return "\(components.day!)" + " days ago".localized()
    } else if (components.day! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 day ago".localized()
        } else {
            return "Yesterday".localized()
        }
    } else if (components.hour! >= 2) {
        return "\(components.hour!)" + " hours ago".localized()
    } else if (components.hour! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 hour ago".localized()
        } else {
            return "An hour ago".localized()
        }
    } else if (components.minute! >= 2) {
        return "\(components.minute!)" + " minutes ago".localized()
    } else if (components.minute! >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 minute ago".localized()
        } else {
            return "A minute ago".localized()
        }
    } else if (components.second! >= 3) {
        return "\(components.second!)" + " seconds ago".localized()
    } else {
        return "Just now".localized()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `NSDate` object to pass into the function, like this:

```
// Create a NSDate object using the current time
let now = NSDate()
let timeString = timeAgoSinceDate(date: now, numericDates: false)
```